# Is there a way to avoid the consent pop-ups that comes up when we request for new access token on expiry of old one?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, access-token, google-identity

On migration to google Identity Service library, with implicit code flow used for authentication, we request for new access token on expiry of old one which results into a consent pop-up. Consent pop-up after every one hour has impacted the user experience. Is there any solution that can help with automatic silent refresh of access token(without any consent pop-ups)?

As per the official documentation of google identity service,
**'none' Do not display any authentication or consent screens. Must not be specified with other values.**
I tried keeping prompt as none.
prompt:'none'
Still it displayed consent pop-up on refresh of access token.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this using the implicit flow unfortunately.

As part of this migration, you will need to start using the Authorisation Code flow.

This Authorisation Code is a bit more complicated (not a lot) and gives you an Authentication code which you can exchange for an Access + Refresh token. With the Refresh token, you will be able to refresh the Access token without having to prompt the user for consent again.

[This is the relevant doc.](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model)